# Problem in displaying correct positions of adjacent letters in hangman

Tags: python

```
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel", "apple"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

print(chosen_word)

guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
display = []
for underscores in range(1, len(chosen_word) + 1):
    display.append("_")
    
pos = 0
for each_word in chosen_word:
    pos += 1
    if each_word == guess:
        display.remove(display[pos - 1])
        display.insert(pos - 1, guess) 
        each_word = guess
print (display)
```

I am making a hangman game, This code is supposed to choose the word from the list of  `word_list` and then produce underscores equal to `len()` of the word. After taking the input it replaces the underscore in **display** variable at the specific position but the problem here is that when i enter a letter that are adjacent in the word choosen like **o** in **baboon**
it displays the result like this:
`["_","_","o","_","o","_"]`
for the word **baboon** and word guessed **0**

I expect the result:`["_","_","_","o","o","_"]`

I have found the solution through another method but I just want to know what is the problem in this current code that is producing such results

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem. 
Then ask a specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)
Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: What do you think `remove` does?

Answer (score 0):

[Definition of remove](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

> `list.remove(x)`
> Remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to x. It raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

You are removing the first instance of "_". Your code works for the first "o", but on the second "o", instead of removing the "_" at index 4, you are removing it from the start of `display` and you end up with:

```py
"_","_","o","_","_"
```

Now when you insert at index 4, you will get:

```py
"_","_","o","_","o","_"
```

I suggest using `for i in range(len(chosen_word))` and just replacing the corresponding character with `display[i] = guess`

Comment: Well, I am confused when I have mentioned the index in the remove() method then why its not removing the "_" at the specific index. I replaced my list with ["1", "2", "3", "4" ,"5", "6"] and used the same code and it worked accurately the result printed was
 ["1", "2", "3", "o" ,"o", "6"]

Comment: From the official definition, `remove` doesn't take an index, only an argument to check equality. If you want to use an index, use `del` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this version:

```
import random

word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel", "apple"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

print(chosen_word)

guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
display = []
for underscores in range(1, len(chosen_word) + 1):
    display.append("_")
    
# pos = 0
# for each_word in chosen_word:
#     pos += 1
#     if each_word == guess:
#         display.remove(display[pos - 1])
#         display.insert(pos - 1, guess) 
# #         each_word = guess


pos = 0
for each_word in chosen_word:
    pos += 1
    if each_word == guess:
        display[pos - 1] = guess
        

print (display)
```

and let us know if it behaves differently ( see answer above)